# Ruby simple_form renders 3 fields for date input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am using the ruby gem simple_form for different forms around my site and was wondering if there was a way to combine/collapse the date input that is rendered by default:

```
= f.input :dob, label: "Date of Birth", as: :date, start_year: Time.now.year - 90, end_year: Time.now.year - 8, order: [:day, :month, :year]
```

This code produces three input field: day, month and year. But what I actually want is to have a single field for all the three, so the input could look like "05/05/1980". How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You passed :as param with wrong.
using string type will make one field instead of 3 fields.

```
= f.input :dob, label: "Date of Birth", as: :string, start_year: Time.now.year - 90, end_year: Time.now.year - 8, order: [:day, :month, :year]
```

Answer (score 8):

In order to use html5 date fields you can do the following:

```
= f.input :dob, as: :string, input_html: {type: :date}
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution will be use jquery datepicker. default datepicker return this format. and your simple form input should be normal text field. pretty and easy solution

Comment: I don't think that a datepicker will be very userfriendly for birthdates? Without using simple_form it returns the field in the right way while it's still technically a date input. So I don't think this is the right solution in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is text with a optional datepicker.

Check this Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery datepicker as:

```
= f.input :dob
```

and

```
$(function() {
  $("input#id_of_dob_field").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about adding the html5: true option? will give you a single field. Does look a bit funny though.

```
= f.input :dob, label: "Date of Birth", as: :date, start_year: Time.now.year - 90, end_year: Time.now.year - 8, order: [:day, :month, :year], html5: true
```